# How I can copy files to to mounted (nfs) directory?

Tags: mount, nfs

I mount a remote folder via:

`sudo mount --bind  ip:/from_folder ~/to_folder`

When I try to copy a folder mounted folder (remote server) via:

`cp -r ~/some_folder ip:/from_folder`

I've got the error:

`cp: cannot create directory '~/to_folder/some_folder': Permission denied`

What can be done in order to copy files to remote server ?

Comment: Well the message points to a permissions error, have you checked permissions on bother servers to ensure the user who is trying to copy the files has permissions to do so?

Comment: Explore your permission/ownership problems with https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld A `bash` script to answer "Why can't I Read/Write that file?".

Comment: I will check and update